# Civimail Plain text unwanted <p> tags

Tags: civimail

I get an unwanted pair of paragraph tags at the top and bottom of my plain text messages. Any ideas how to get rid of this?

John
Civi 4.6.10
Drupal 7.41

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out. I had a "blank" header and footer selected by default. When I removed them... problem solved.

Comment: you can 'accept' your own answer